# How to improve perfomance of CNN and reduce overfitting?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, overfitting-underfitting

I am working on a small computer vision project and I'm using convolutional nets for classification. I have already used dropout, l1, l2 regularization and data augmentation to reduce overfitting. Are there any other techniques and algorithms for improving model accuracy and reducing overfitting?

Comment: (1)-Add more data (2)-Use smaller CNN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there could be a 100 solutions

1. Use pretrained model (transfer learning).
2. Try to implement a smaller network.
3. Bigger data set.
4. Try different parameters[learning rate, batch size..].
5. Use grid search for these parameters.
6. Try data augmentation for your training data set.
   ...

Comment: *there could be a 100 solutions* ... which is why we discourage posting answers to questions that are unclear in their requirements.